# Sqlite using memory even after the python script is done

Tags: python, sqlite, jupyter-notebook, airflow

I am running Airflow scheduler which read a Jupyter notebook including a process which stores data in an Sqlite database. The issue is that when it is done with storing in the database, I end up with a bunch or rows similar to the following that I could see when I run `ps -aux`.
Is there an option to avoid this? The memory used keep growing if I run this process everyday and don't restart my Docker container or kill the process.

```
 usr/local/bin/python -m ipykernel_launcher -f /tmp/tmppohm7rar.json --HistoryManager.hist_file=:memory:
```

Airflow Dag:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.papermill.operators.papermill import PapermillOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": datetime(2015, 6, 1),
    "email": ["airflow@airflow.com"],
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "retries": 30,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}


with DAG(
    dag_id='PTS_WORFLOW',
    schedule_interval='0 0 * * *',
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    tags=['PTS'],
) as dag_1:

    t0 = PapermillOperator(
        task_id="20210511_MMLIB",
        input_nb="/opt/airflow/script/PTS_Tools/20210511_DATADOWN_RETRY/20210511_MMLIB.ipynb",
        output_nb="/tmp/out-{{ execution_date }}.ipynb",
    t1 = PapermillOperator(
        task_id="000_MAKE_DB_BASE_PARQ",
        input_nb="/opt/airflow/script/PTS_Tools/20210521_FLOW/000_MAKE_DB_BASE_PARQ.ipynb",
        output_nb="/tmp/out-{{ execution_date }}.ipynb",
    )

    t2 = PapermillOperator(
        task_id="001_MAKE_XPF_DATA",
        input_nb="/opt/airflow/script/PTS_Tools/20210521_FLOW/001_MAKE_XPF_DATA.ipynb",
        output_nb="/tmp/out-{{ execution_date }}.ipynb",
    )

    t3 = PapermillOperator(
        task_id="002_MAKE_BASE_TARGET_FROM_XLS",
        input_nb="/opt/airflow/script/PTS_Tools/20210521_FLOW/002_MAKE_BASE_TARGET_FROM_XLS.ipynb",
        output_nb="/tmp/out-{{ execution_date }}.ipynb",
    )

    t4 = PapermillOperator(
        task_id="003_MAKE_TARGET_DATA",
        input_nb="/opt/airflow/script/PTS_Tools/20210521_FLOW/003_MAKE_TARGET_DATA.ipynb",
        output_nb="/tmp/out-{{ execution_date }}.ipynb",
    )

    t5 = PapermillOperator(
        task_id="004_MAKE_BIDDER_DATA",
        input_nb="/opt/airflow/script/PTS_Tools/20210521_FLOW/004_MAKE_BIDDER_DATA.ipynb",
        output_nb="/tmp/out-{{ execution_date }}.ipynb",
    )
    t6 = PapermillOperator(
        task_id="005_MAKE_MERGED_TARGETDATA",
        input_nb="/opt/airflow/script/PTS_Tools/20210521_FLOW/005_MAKE_MERGED_TARGETDATA.ipynb",
        output_nb="/tmp/out-{{ execution_date }}.ipynb",
    )

    t7 = PapermillOperator(
        task_id="006_ORGANIZE_NEW_PTSDB",
        input_nb="/opt/airflow/script/PTS_Tools/20210521_FLOW/006_ORGANIZE_NEW_PTSDB.ipynb",
        output_nb="/tmp/out-{{ execution_date }}.ipynb",
    )

    t8 = PapermillOperator(
        task_id="007_ORGANIZE_NEW_PTSDB",
        input_nb="/opt/airflow/script/PTS_Tools/20210521_FLOW/007_ORGANIZE_NEW_PTSDB.ipynb",
        output_nb="/tmp/out-{{ execution_date }}.ipynb",
    )

    cmd = 'sudo rm -rf /opt/airflow/downloads/* /opt/airflow/dl_from_volume/*'
    cmd_1 = 'find /opt/airflow/script/PTS_Tools/20210521_FLOW/data -type f ! -name "*.db" -delete'

    t9 = BashOperator(
        task_id='008_CLEAN_UP_PROCESS_1',
        bash_command=cmd
    )
    t9 = BashOperator(
        task_id='008_CLEAN_UP_PROCESS_1',
        bash_command=cmd
    )

    t10 = BashOperator(
        task_id='009_CLEAN_UP_PROCESS_2',
        bash_command=cmd_1
    )

    t3 >> t5 >> t7
    t0 >> t3 >> t4 >> t6 >> t7 >> t8 >> t9 >> t10
    t6 >> t7 >> t8 >> t9 >> t10
    t1 >> t2 >> t6
                                                                                                                                                                     104,9         Bot
```

Comment: It solely depends on how you are running your `python` command. I think it's your custom  code that executes it. You need to  add some more information on how you are running it

Comment: @jerekPotiuk thank you. Airflow read the DAG above. See my edit.

Comment: Might be a bug in PapermillOperator then.

Comment: You might want to open a GitHub Issue - with all the details you have, logs etc. https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues